# Access JS file Functions from Jquery Dialog Form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a div containing a form. I use that div as a dialog using jquery UI dialog.

There are buttons in the form. I want to call methods from my JS file attached to the view when buttons are clicked.

Somehow the dialog can not find the functions.

HTML

```
<div id="Applon" title="Edit Slab" style="width: 100%; background-color: #33CCCC;">
<form action="\" id="frmDtl">
....
......


<button id="dtlCancel"  type="button" onclick="this.parent.CancelDetails()" style="font-weight: bold; color: #3333FF; width:60px;">
<div><span>Cancel</span></div>  
</button>
</form>
</div>
```

JS file

```
$(function() {
//  Dialog

    $("#Applon").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 370,
        width: 650,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {

            Close: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                //$('input:visible:enabled:first').focus();
            }
        },
        close: function() {
        }
    });
});

    function CancelDetails() {
        ....
    }
```

I am using this in a MVC2 view in VS2008. The view has two forms one of which is a dialog.

How do i make the dialog find my functions in the JS file when button is clicked ?

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try and go away from inline Javascript and use selectors to fire off your functions.  For instance,

```
$(function() {
   $("#dtlCancel").click(function(){
     CancelDetails();
  });
});
```

You can place this in your modal content if it is from a separate resource (PartialView).

Also, is your dialog an IFrame or just a modal?  If it is just a modal, it is still part of the page it came from and does not need references to "parent".  Consider it a well-placed div that appears to be another page.

**EDIT**

Looking at your JS code file, it still looks like you are missing the closing brace for your $(function(){ statement

Your Code:

```
$(function() {
//  Dialog

    $("#Applon").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 370,
        width: 650,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {

            Close: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                //$('input:visible:enabled:first').focus();
            }
        },
        close: function() {
        }
    });
//From your code above (next line)
    }
//Replace the above with this - basically add a ); after the curly brace
});

    function CancelDetails() {
        ....
    }
```

Comment: It is just a modal. No Iframe.

Comment: Tried your suggestion . I am still geting Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected Error.

Comment: Is your Function CancelDetails inside of the $(function(){ ?  It appears that it is, it should be outside of that block since it is its own function

Comment: what is inside of the CancelDetails function?  Can you replace the function call with those contents?  Are we sure that something inside of the CancelDetails function is not causing the error?

Comment: currently there is no logic inside the CancelDetails.

Comment: Take a look at what I just posted, I think you are missing the ); from your $(function(){ statement.  The only }); that I see corresponds with your .dialog handler...

Comment: Thank You Tommy but my actual code contains 2 jqgrid decarations and many more. I just copied and pasted only the relevant code. I double checked and there is no missing brace. The problem is the plugin expects the buttons to be defined in the initialization code which i am not doing. as long as i define buttons and their events within dialog definition it works fine. But the problem is i cant place the  buttons where i want so i defined the buttons out side the dialog definition. The code inside the dialog can not reach any function in my JS file. Some thing is fishy here.

Comment: @Deb - gotcha, well at least you have it narrowed down.  Sorry I couldn't be more help!